# app not showing in Android wear start menu

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api, android-wear-notification

I am creating an app that supports both mobile and wearable. 
What I have done so far is:

- correctly included wear module in `build.gradle` [as mentioned here](http://dejan.djurovski.net/2014/10/02/adding-an-android-wear-component-to-an-existing-android-studio-project/)
- added correct dependedncies and support libraries for wearables
- same `package name` and `application id` both both - wear and mobile modules
- same permissions in both `manifest`
- added `meta-data` for wearable app launcher icon as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879271/android-wear-app-not-showing-up-in-start-menu-on-watch)
- installed signed apk in device.

But, still my launcher icon is not showing in Android Wear start menu.

I have checked all above mentioned things twice. Is anything missing? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you solve your issue?